# What does a native speaker say when his pain reduces after taking medicine?

Tags: word-request

What does a native speaker say when his pain reduces gradually after taking medicine? Is it, "My pain is easing", or something else?

Comment: "The pain is easing" or "going away". "It [the medicine] is helping" among other possibilities.

Comment: If one is just *talking* (about) medicine, it's the *placebo effect*.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No, this is about taking real medicine which is taking effect. Morphine, for instance, doesn't produce the placebo effect.

Comment: Please note: we don't say the pain reduces. Pain does not reduce. Pain **is reduced** by taking A, B or C. It has to be passive in English.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, what is normally said is

> The morphine is kicking in.

(Substitute name of painkiller as appropriate.)

Answer (score 0):

We usually say "pain relief" or "pain easing"/"to ease pain"

- [Relief pain meaning](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/relieving)
- [Ease pain meaning](https://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/to+ease+pain)

Answer (score 0):

Options:

- The pain eased after taking the medication.
- The pain tapered off after taking the medication.
- The pain reduced after taking the medication.
- The pain was lessened after taking the medication.

If the pain went away completely, you might say:

- The pain ceased after taking the medication.
- The pain ended after taking the medication.

Comment: Any of the first four answers could also be used naturally with *present continuous*, which I believe is the OP's question, based on the guess they made about *"my pain is easing"*, despite the wording of the question itself

Comment: (the) pain was reduced because pain can't take reduce anything. And we  generally say: after I took the medication.

Answer (score 0):

Other options include "I feel better now", "It hurts less", "The painkillers kicked in and that helped take the edge off", " I think the oxy is starting to hit", or perhaps "The(/my) pain went down after taking ... " Or "my (part of body) is getting better"/"my pain is starting to go away".

Answer (score 0):

In English, if you take a medication for pain (let's say a headache), you can do one of two things:

1. Talk about how **you feel**:

**I feel better**.
**I am better now.**
**My head or leg** or whatever doesn't hurt as much. Or: is no longer bothering me.

OR
2) Talk about **the medication**:

- This aspirin works very well. My headache is not so bad now.
- The aspirin worked. I no longer have a headache.
- The aspirin is working or taking effect. My headache is easing.

All the other suggestions gives such as the pain has eased, the pills have kicked in, the pills have relieved the pain are all correct also.